# В Qt кнопка не отображает иконку

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Здравствуйте.
Построил форму в QtCreator, всё красиво, скомпилировал, на кнопках нет иконок и виджет GraphicsView криво расположен. Ничего не смог сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает.
Заранее благодарю.

[image: Qt bug.]

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что под IDE программа не находит путь к иконкам. Стартовый каталог не совпадает. А кривое выравнивание это потому что конструктор и библиотека вычисляют размеры по разному. Да и кнопки делают слишком большой отступ для изображений. Недоработки! Я просто увеличил фиксированный размер окна на 10px от рассчитанного конструктором. Ну и что продолжать после этого играть в Qt? Сколько еще "подводных камней" впереди?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для расположения виджетов используйте компоновщики, иконки храните в ресурсах. Все хорошо с Qt. В сравнении с другими подобными фреймворками/библиотеками он лучший :)

И указывайте в следующий раз версию Qt и Qt Creator

Comment: Возможно коммерческая линия не имеет недостатков. У меня **Qt Creator 3.5.0**,  на **Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 5.2.1 20151010, 64 бита)**. Почти как **Delphi** :).

Comment: Разница между коммерческой и бесплатной в лицензии :)

Comment: Сборщик ресурсов -- файл с описанием путей к другим файлам, используемых в программе. Насколько я помню, при компиляции он попадет в исполняемый файл (например, ехе). Если используете Qt Creator, то он хорошо умеет создавать и заполнять файлы ресурсов. Вообще, погуглите, там все очень просто. Да и в самой Qt очень клевая документация

Comment: Исправив это недоразумение и осмотрев систему могу сказать. Qt вещь очень лаконичная и систематическая, ничего лишнего. И интерфейс собирается так же просто и быстро как и в Delphi. Отличная среда для разработки.