# Как подключить логику приложения к интерфейсу Qt?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Здравствуйте.
Я начинающий в разработке на Qt. Изучал материалы сайта но так и не нашел ни детальных рекомендаций ни развернутых примеров. Я начал использовать эту среду для кросс проектирования под Linux/C++ и затрудняюсь с продвижением. Мне нужно подключить низкоуровневый интерфейс на С к модели сгенерированной Qt Creator.
**Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно почитать толковый учебник?** Мой прошлый опыт работы с Delphi почему то не помог.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: В чем конкретно состоит ваша проблема? Формулируйте точнее.

Comment: @gbg Хорошо. Задача несложная. Я делаю [симулятор терминала](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524768/%D0%92-qt-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83) для простейшего контроллера. Есть "кухонная" OS нужен GUI приборного типа строго только на С. Для моделирования и демонстрации в среде С работы специальной аппаратуры. **Как сделать обработчик событий этой модели без интервенции в код сгенерированный Qt Creator?**

Comment: вы хотите "странного" - использовать фреймворк на чистом C++ для работы с кодом на C. Код на C компонуется с кодом на C++ при помощи нехитрого блока extern С {} в заголовочном файле. Просто вызывайте свои функции на C из кода на C++ и все. Но смешение стилей - это великая глупость, не несущая смысла.

Comment: Это не глупость а обычная практика в профессиональном программировании. Предложите лучшую среду для моделирования  на С, если вы такой умный.  Только не RAD от Ambarcadero, это дорого. Извините.

Comment: хотите GUI строго на C - используйте GTK. Никаких абсолютно преимуществ в написании GUI у C перед C++ нет.

Более того, GUI - код на C будет представлять собой уродское уродство по сравнению с кодом на C++, его будет дороже сопровождать и так далее. Эмулятор терминала (ага, в многозадачной среде не реального времени) - не та задача, где нужно такты считать.

Comment: В модели реального времени не нужно, важна только логика, нужно получить надежный переносимый код. Так все делают. А о GTK я как то не подумал. Я не очень хорошо знаю "большие" машины. Посмотрю, спасибо. А смешение языков это обычное дело, порой даже необходимое.

Comment: надежный и переносимый код вы получите на C++. Причем переносимый в нескольких плоскостях - от системы к системе и от программиста к программисту. Если вы возьмете любого программиста с рынка труда, и скажете - пишите GUI на C и GTK вы получите воочию пот этот смайл 0_0 и вежливый вопрос - "Вы чо, из 1995 года сюда свалились?"

Сейчас GUI вообще хорошо пишется с использованием веб-технологий. Потому как браузер с поддержкой JS есть на любой табуретке. И даже RS232 поддерживается.

Comment: Да я с 1995 года свалился. Вы просто не поняли. Я занимаюсь встраиваемыми системами повышенной надежности, с экстремально малыми аппаратными ресурсами. А JS на наших табуретках не помещается.

Comment: как ни странно, я тоже. Только у меня почему-то хватает соображения не тащить крохоборские методики из восьмибитной attiny на персоналку с полтерабайтом оперативки

Comment: Зря вы так, AVR замечательный и эффективный код. Все наоборот. Прототипирование программ вам известно?

Comment: разумеется, известно - спектран с частотой семплирования 41кГц и Фурье в реальном времени на atmega8 я делал, начав с прототипа на персоналке.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40052/discussion-between--and-gbg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Толковый учебник - [Шлее](http://vk.com/max.schlee) [Qt 5.3. Профессиональное программирование на C++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31619787/)

Comment: Спасибо. А даром, что нибудь есть?

Comment: @Вячеслав, даром - http://doc.qt.io/

Comment: @PavelParshin Ну да, за ангаром. :)

Comment: @Вячеслав, даром должна быть более старая версия этого учебника. Для изучения основ, можно использовать и учебник по Qt 4. Принципиальной разницы нет, чтобы стартовать. А вообще, цена аз книгу в ~900 рублей не должна быть для программиста проблемой.

Comment: У на с вами война, к сожалению. Для меня сейчас всё проблема. Стартовал я лет 30 назад. Не могу найти как перехватить поток событий от кнопок, и их декларацию, подскажите если знаете.

Comment: @Вячеслав - пишете метод-слот, затем привязываете к нему событие от кнопки. 
код, который генерирует qtcreator - это ровно то, что нужно для того, чтобы построить морду приложения и передавать события. Ничего лишнего там нет.

Comment: Qt конечно вещь красивая но зачем было вводить **signal, slot, emit,** и использовать этот препроцессор *moc* , компилятором его как то язык не поворачивается назвать. Delphi из С++ все равно не получится а код стал нестандартный.

Comment: @gbg Спасибо, я так и предполагал.

Comment: @Вячеслав это нужно для того, чтобы достроить C++ до удобного объектно-ориентированного языка, на котором написание событийно-управляемого приложения выглядит естественно. Тот факт, что MOC выдает не бинарник, а исходник, не делает его препроцессором - это именно компилятор. Более того, последние стандарты C++ в скором времени позволят вышвырнуть moc.

Comment: @gbg Да возможно так и будет, Qt очень популярна. Как сделали в свое время Delphi из Object Pascal.

Comment: @gbg Все отыскалось, все Ок. Дело пошло. Морда, кстати штука не простая а без графических конструкторов быстро и красиво не сделаешь.